# MVC Razor EditorFor Display Field help when hover over field aka tooltip

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

For a data entry field I want to display a hint for the user when they hover over the field.  The field name is  INACT and  indicates if the record has been inactivated.  Something like this is what is needed - Enter an I to Inactivate a record.

I have this in the ModelMetadata

```
    [Display(Name = "INACT")]
    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = true)]
    [StringLength(1)]
    public string A_INACT;
```

And display in the Inact View -   This view is the only place this field can be edited.
 :

```
    <div class="editor-label">    
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.A_INACT) 
   </div>
   <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.A_INACT , new { htmlAttributes = new { tabindex = 1 } })                
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model =>Model.A_INACT)   
   </div>
```

The INACT View

```
  @model MTSapp.Models.mts_rename

   @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Inact";

   }
  <style>
   .container {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
   }
  </style>

 <h2>RE NAME </h2>
  <h2>Inact Re Number</h2>

 @using (Html.BeginForm())
{

@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>mts_rename</legend>

<br />



<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.A_ID)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.A_ID, new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly", @style = "background:#f2f3f3", tabindex = 4 })
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.A_RENO)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.A_RENO, new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly", @style = "background:#f2f3f3", tabindex = 5 })
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.A_INACT)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    <span class="SpaceAvailableSearch">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.A_INACT, new { htmlAttributes = new { tabindex = 1, title = "Enter I to Inactivate Record" } }) </span>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.A_INACT)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.A_NAME)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.A_NAME, new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly", @style = "background:#f2f3f3", tabindex = 6, @title = "This is the RE NAME." })
</div>




<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</p>
</fieldset>
 }

 <div>
   @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
 </div>

 @section Scripts {
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
 }
```

[Inact Page displayed in IE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jq4h.png)

This is the View Source:

```
      <!DOCTYPE HTML>
      <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Inact -  MTS Application</title>
        <link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

        <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.5.3.js"></script>

        <link href="/Content/Myspec" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <link href="/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


      </head>
      <body>
        <header>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <p class="site-title"><a href="/">MATERIAL TEST SYSTEM</a></p>
                </div>

                <div class="float-right">
                    <section id="login">
                        Hello how are you today, <span class="username">AHTD\mase347</span>!
                    </section>
                    <nav>
                        <ul id="menu">
                            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/Home/Login">Login</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/Home/About">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/Home/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div id="body">

            <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">

<style>
    .container {
        width: 50%;
        float: left;
    }
</style>

<h2>RE NAME </h2>
<h2>Inact Re Number</h2>

<form action="/MTS_RENAME/Inact/1" method="post">    <fieldset>
        <legend>mts_rename</legend>

        <br />



        <div class="editor-label">
           <label for="A_ID">ID</label> 
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
           <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ID must be a number." data-val-required="The ID field is required." id="A_ID" name="A_ID" readonly="readonly" style="background:#f2f3f3" tabindex="4" type="text" value="1" /> 
        </div>

         <div class="editor-label">
          <label for="A_RENO">RE NUMBER</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
          <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-length="The field RE NUMBER must be a string with a maximum length of 3." data-val-length-max="3" id="A_RENO" name="A_RENO" readonly="readonly" style="background:#f2f3f3" tabindex="5" type="text" value="1" />
        </div>

         <div class="editor-label">
          <label for="A_INACT">INACT</label> 
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
         <span class="SpaceAvailableSearch"> <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-length="The field INACT must be a string with a maximum length of 1." data-val-length-max="1" id="A_INACT" name="A_INACT" type="text" value="" /> </span>
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="A_INACT" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span> 
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
         <label for="A_NAME">RE NAME</label> 
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
          <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-length="The field RE NAME must be a string with a maximum length of 39." data-val-length-max="39" data-val-required="The RE NAME field is required." id="A_NAME" name="A_NAME" readonly="readonly" style="background:#f2f3f3" tabindex="6" title="This is the RE NAME." type="text" value="ZZ_TESTXDO THIS ZZXXXX" />
        </div>




        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
<div>
    <a href="/MTS_RENAME">Back to List</a>
</div>


            </section>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <p>&copy; 2017 - My ASP.NET MVC Application</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>

        <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>

        <script src="/bundles/bootstrap"></script>


    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>


    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HTML has a `title` attribute for a tooltip like this.  (For anything more complex than a basic tooltip, you'd be looking at some custom styling and possibly JavaScript functionality to mimic a tooltip, depending on the approach taken.  There are a variety of ready-made solutions available via Google for this.)

So where you set your custom HTML attributes:

```
htmlAttributes = new { tabindex = 1 }
```

You can simply add one for the `title`:

```
htmlAttributes = new { tabindex = 1, title = "Enter an I to Inactivate a record" }
```

Comment: Thank you  @David - that is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: For the EditorFor  when I add the title = "Enter an I to Inactivate a record"  to the  htmlAttributes   the tooltip  does not work and breaks the tabindex = 1 .  It also  does not work if  the  title = "Enter an I to Inactivate a record"   is used by itself.   Thinking maybe using the TextBoxFor  instead.

Comment: @farmer: Define "does not work" and "breaks".  Is there a server-side error?  Or what HTML does it generate?

Comment: Not seeing any Errors on the screen and nothing  in Visual Studio  - this is running my computer at the moment.    The  Tooltip does not work - when you hover over the INPUT box nothing shows up on the screen where "Enter an I to Inactivate a record"  should be displayed.  And the tabindex=1  breaks  - when you  click on the screen anywhere and tab - it should(does without the title=) click to the INACT field, instead it  click to another field I have on the screen - which happens to be a TextBoxFor .  When I remove the title=   then tabindex=1   focuses on the INACT field.

Comment: My Pproject is  using MVC 4 and I don't think this works  until MVC 5.  May look at what I have to do to get to MVC 5.

Comment: @farmer: Again, what actual HTML gets generated?

Comment: Do you want a copy of the view Source after it's displayed?  I can put a copy in the question

Comment: @farmer: Well, at the very least you'll want to take a look at the relevant `<input>` element.

Comment: added the View Source and Code

Comment: Know this is old - but just converted to MVC5 and this worked great  with Html.EditorFor.  It was SO worth upgrading to MVC5

Answer (score 1):

you mean something like this?

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.A_INACT , new { @title="Enter an I to Inactivate a record." })
```

Or, if you want something more fancy, i would use jquery's tooltip
https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

Comment: Thanks for the help! and the reference to tooltip

Comment: Seems not to work for EditorFor  so may switch this to  TextBoxFor .  The  tabindex=1 does work without the title= , and the title= does not work by itself.

Comment: Converted my project  to MVC5 and this worked great with Html.EditorFor. It was SO worth upgrading to MVC5.