# How to display localized text rendered from javascript in a razor cshtml view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, localization

We display a tooltip on mouse enter that gives a hint about the field over which they hover. We would like to localize that text. All other localized text in the view is localized using resource bundles and are loaded using something like @Localizer"My text"). But on mouse enter the text is rendered by the js. SO how does one localize that in a razor view.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47203361/mvc-razor-editorfor-display-field-help-when-hover-over-field-aka-tooltip

Comment: Not sure how this helps. This refers to the html title attribute. I'm using a custom tooltip generated via javascript.

Comment: I've actually found a solution. I can use a data attribute, data-loc-text="@Localizer["my text"]". And then use query to set the title on my tooltip.